# Using setlist and skipping numbers

Tags: numbering

So I'm doing my homework in LaTeX where I'm using this...

```
\setlist[Problem]{label={Problem-2.\arabic*:},leftmargin=*}
```

To be able to use `\item` so I get results like...

```
Problem-2.6:
```

I like and prefer this format but I've run into an issue where the questions I need to answer are jumping around.

Is there a way to skip so that I can do something like...

```
Problem-2.6:
Problem-2.13:
```

Where there won't be any items in between 6 and 13?

Comment: Add `\setcounter{Problemi}{12}` after the `\item` that is Problem-2-6. (Assuming you are using the `enumitem` package. ... this is why you should nearly always provide an MWE, by the way.)

Comment: Thanks jon!  Why not add it as answer so that I can mark it?

Comment: Well, I wasn't 100% sure you were using `enumitem` (though the `\setlist` was a pretty strong hint).

Comment: Ah ok cool.  Sorry about that.  I'll be sure to include package next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `enumitem` makes this pretty easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{Problem}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[Problem]{label={Problem-2.\arabic*:},leftmargin=*}
\begin{document}

\begin{Problem}
  \item One
  \item Two
    \setcounter{Problemi}{12}
  \item Thirteen
\end{Problem}

\end{document}
```